# How to sum up the next 10 weeks sum based on another column?

Tags: sql, databricks

So I have this issue where I need to sum up the next 10 weeks based on the value another column

The current selection I have is:

```
SELECT Year, Week, Brand, Brandtype, current_date() AS Date, COUNT(Player_ID) AS Number_of_players
FROM table
WHERE Week IS NOT NULL
```

So my desired output is to sum up Number_of_players for the next 10 weeks from todays week. Btw, The week column contians predictions for the next weeks to come

Comment: Is week a number value relating to week?

Comment: Yes, the week column is a week number (42, 18, 32 etc..)

Comment: something like this maybe `FROM table as t WHERE t.week is not null and week>=10 and week<20
group by t.Year, t.Week, t.Brand, t.Brandtype`  You will need to get the current week and change 10 and 20 for that and that + 10.  Also, you'll need to handle the over laps.  Is there an actual date in there which would make the logic a bit easier